# disable company-mode when editing C++ over tramp

Tags: tramp, company-mode

When editing Python files over tramp, elpy continues to use my local python distribution for completion, which is fine by be for what I need.

However, when editing C++, it uses `clang` output from the remote host and the round-trip is constantly hanging my editor.  Right now I just manually disable company-mode, but I am wondering how I can include a hook that says, when editing C++ over tramp, turn off `company-mode`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely untested:

```
(add-hook
 'c++-mode-hook
 (lambda () (when (file-remote-p default-directory) (company-mode -1))))
```

Comment: you sir... rock